# Successfully adding the class into the element but not effecting the element

Tags: javascript

[image: show class adding to the elemet but doesnt work]

i am adding the show class Successfully to the element but somehow the show class is not working.

```
const obeserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});
const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => obeserver.observe(el));
```

and css

```
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translate(0);
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.show` is before `.hidden` in the css file

Swap the order:

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: translate(-100%);
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translate(0);
}
```